# Where to put the properties file in web app folder in Struts 1.3?

Tags: java, jsp, tags, javabeans, struts-1

I am making a simple web app using struts 1.3 .

It contains a simple registration page which uses `<bean:message` > tag.

I have set the path of my properties file in struts-config.xml file as:

```
<message-resources parameter="resources.Application" />
```

the file is named : Application.properties and is stored as shown below:

WEB-INF---classes----resources---Application.properties

The page is giving me error :

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Cannot find message resources under key org.apache.struts.action.MESSAGE
```

What could be the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I think struts will look for that file in WEB-INF/classes/resources.Application.properties

Comment: it will (or should if it doesn't) in fact look for WEB-INF/classes/resources/Application.properties
Or for a file ./resources/Application.properties somewhere in a jar contained in the WEB-INF/lib or any of the application server shared lib directory.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, without moving your file anywhere.

```
<message-resources parameter="Application" />
```

Comment: Okk. But now i have a new error : org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Module 'null' not found.

Comment: @Lokesh: The best way to resolve a `NullPointerException` is to go to the line number mentioned in the exception. You can provide the full stack trace by editing your answer.